# I wanted to insert the below value into postgresql, which data type I needed to use and how I consturct insert Query?

Tags: postgresql

the data is json array

```
[{ "customer": "John Doe", "items": {"product": "Beer","qty": 6}}, { "staff" : "Jack" }]
```

Comment: provide your structure please. the topic does not correlate with body much

Comment: Why do you use `json[]` in the first place? `json` *can* contain JSON arrays, there is no need to mix it with PostgreSQL's native arrays. Are there any specific reason to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it as `json` (or `jsonb`)

```
create table sameesh
(
   data json
);

insert into sameesh (data)
values 
('[{ "customer": "John Doe", "items": {"product": "Beer","qty": 6}}, { "staff" : "Jack" }]');
```